# Android : What is the equivalent of XMLHttpRequest JavaScript?

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I would like to implement an Http Request connexion in chunk mode. In **JavaScript**, i use **XMLHttpRequest** with **onreadystatechange** callback.

What is the equivalent in Java Android ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: It is my understanding that the transfer-encoding is default to chunked.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you mean you want to make asynchronous request, Have a look at [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) OR a much simpler library [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) for making Asynchronous request

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent would be an [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instance on which you call [`setChunkedStreamingMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode%28int%29) to enable chunk mode when posting content. You need to perform the request on a background thread then post the result back on the main thread, using `AsyncTask` for example.

Answer (score 1):

All the networking work in Android must be done on a thread that isn't the UI thread. To archive this, developers usually work with [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) classes.

For making http calls, Android uses HttpUrlConnection as it´s basis, some good libraries like OkHttp use them in their core. The Android team also recommends to use HttpUrlConnection for networking.
Check this link to get some info about that statement

> http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Here you've a full working image downloading task, based on HttpUrlConnection and AsyncTask

```
public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final static String TAG = ImageDownloaderTask.class.getSimpleName();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final WeakReference imageViewReference;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static Integer mPlaceholder;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public ImageDownloaderTask(Context context, ImageView imageView, Integer placeholder) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference(imageView);
        mContext = context;
        mPlaceholder = placeholder;
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }
        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(mPlaceholder));
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {

        Bitmap bmp =null;
        try{
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                return bmp;
            }catch(Exception e){}
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

You can use this class like this

```
new ImageDownloaderTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myImageView, R.drawable.placeholder_drawable).execute("http://mydomain.com/myImage.png");
```

Hope this help you to clarify your ideas on how to work with HttpUrlConnection and Threads in android.